# python error explanation for build custom logger

Tags: python, error-handling

I'm writing an custom logger and i have some doubts

Error example:

```
(
    <frame object at 0x7f92fc032420>,
    '/home/projects/zpy/private/lib/error.py',
    10,
    'log',
    ['\t\tstack = inspect.stack()\n'],
    0
)
```

1. ?
2. filename
3. Code Line
4. type?
5. Code
6. ?

Can you explain what are the 1,4 and 6 points?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack

When the following functions return “frame records,” each record is a tuple of six items:

1. the frame object
2. the filename
3. the line number of the current line
4. the function name
5. a list of lines of context from the source code
6. and the index of the current line within that list.

thanks to razpeitia